# jquery ajax spotify php bootstrap modal not showing up

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal, fat-free-framework

What I´m trying to accomplish:
Click on image retrieves artist information from spotify api and shall show it as modal.
I achieve to retrieve and show the requested information in console.log and window.alert.
But I just don´t get it to handle it via modal.
I`m fatfree (f3) php framework, bootstrap, jquery.

This is the jquery part:

```
(function(){
    var artistId = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {
      let token =
        "token";
      // todo: get token from php variable
      $("img").click(function() {
        var artistId = $(this).attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + artistId,
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
          success: function(result) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: {myData:result},
              url: "/views/content/artistdetails.php",
              success:
              function(){
                console.log('yes');
                $('.modal').modal('show')
                console.log(result);  
              },
              error: function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
              }
            }
            )
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

artistdetails.php for the modal (Note, I just copied the html from bootstrap, first I need to show it up)

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal" data-toggle="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="getCode">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I went through a lot of articles concerning this topic, I just don´t find the error.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check the console for errors?

Comment: console used to give me the "modal is not a function" error, but that´s fine now, I got rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your modal in the same page where you do the ajax. So, If you want to show the modal, you just run `$('.modal').modal('show')`, but if you want to show the response of Spotify API in the modal, you can do:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal" data-toggle="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Spotify API Response</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="getCode">
                    <p id="getCodeText"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        (function() {
                var artistId = "";
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    let token =
                        "token";
                    // todo: get token from php variable
                    $("img").click(function() {
                        var artistId = $(this).attr("data-id");

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + artistId,
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                console.log(result);
                                // Here you change the text of the <p></p> element in your modal's body.
                                $('#getCodeText').html(result);
                                // Here you show the modal.
                                $('.modal').modal('show');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! And sorry, I still don´t get it. Since I`m using MVC, do I have to pass it to a controller first which then sets the view, which is in this case this artistdetails.php? This MVC still confuses me. I´m on this route: ".../browse/latin". This site´s controller calls the spotify api and shows via browse.html the response (images). When I click an image I make another call and ask spotify for the clicked artist (ajax). The response shall be shown as modal......So did I get it right that your changes should pop up the modal now? It doesn´t.

Comment: For example you have the "Check artist" button (that makes the ajax call) in the view index.html, in that view you need to add at the bottom of the page the modal bootstrap code, and in your javascript you need to replace with the code that I replied earlier. You can't make an ajax call in X page and then use that response to show a modal.

Comment: Ah, got it, and it (partly) works ;). First, I understand, can get rid of the artistdetails.php, not needed. Second, added html and replaced javascript code. I get a modal. Just one thing. On click function gives me the right data of the clicked button (console.log check), but it just shows the last name of the 'result' object. So I think there needs to be some kind of $(this) added?

Comment: I don't understand much of your question. But if the API gives you JSON, you can display the values with `result.(json key)`. If I helped you, please mark my response as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, that`s why I´m confused because it already worked with the window.alert. I have problems how to display the values of an array inside this json object. Many thanks for your help!!!